# Parsing HTML to plain text, but retaining tag information per character

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm looking for a method to parse HTML (or Markdown, but I can convert that into HTML) into plain text, but then identify which tags apply for each character in turn.

So, for instance, if I had the following HTML:

```
<p>Hello <em>world</em>!</p>
```

I would be get the plain text:

```
Hello world!
```

And be able to query different characters to find out which tags apply:

```
Character 0 -> H -> p
Character 1 -> e -> p
Character 2 -> l -> p
...
Character 6 -> w -> p, em
Character 7 -> o -> p, em
...
Character 11 -> ! -> p
```

Can anyone suggest a method of doing this? It sounds like it shouldn't be too difficult, so I suspect I'm just searching for the wrong terminology to find something appropriate.

Ideally this would be using JSoup or something similar, but happy to take other approaches and libraries if they work!

UPDATE: Also, I need to be able to separate adjacent identical tags. So for the HTML:

```
<p>Hello</p><p>World</p>
```

I would be able to identify `p#1` and `p#2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
public void testCharMapping() {
    charMapping("<p>Hello <em>world</em>!</p>");
    charMapping("<p>Hello</p><p>World</p>");
}

private void charMapping(String html) {
    System.out.println("char mapping for : " + html);
    for (Element e : Jsoup.parse(html).select("*")) {
        if (e.ownText() != null && !e.ownText().isEmpty())
            for (char c : e.ownText().toCharArray())
                System.out.println(c + " -> " + e.cssSelector());
    }
    System.out.println("====================");
}
```

Respone:

```
char mapping for : <p>Hello <em>world</em>!</p>
H -> html > body > p
e -> html > body > p
l -> html > body > p
l -> html > body > p
o -> html > body > p
  -> html > body > p
! -> html > body > p
w -> html > body > p > em
o -> html > body > p > em
r -> html > body > p > em
l -> html > body > p > em
d -> html > body > p > em
====================
char mapping for : <p>Hello</p><p>World</p>
H -> html > body > p:nth-child(1)
e -> html > body > p:nth-child(1)
l -> html > body > p:nth-child(1)
l -> html > body > p:nth-child(1)
o -> html > body > p:nth-child(1)
W -> html > body > p:nth-child(2)
o -> html > body > p:nth-child(2)
r -> html > body > p:nth-child(2)
l -> html > body > p:nth-child(2)
d -> html > body > p:nth-child(2)
====================
```

Comment: This does not maintain the order of chars. I.e. '!' is before 'world'. With Jsoup getting order of chars might be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a stack based parsing for the html tags and for the strings inside, the position can be stored while popping out elements from the stack.

Comment: Start reading characters one by one. look for a open bracket < and the string following by upto a closing >. This marks a start tag. Put this tag in the stack. After this, look whatever follows upto another <\ is a text in the html which can be printed. Print all the characters upto </ and you will find the closing tag. If the closing tag contains same string as the top element tag then you can pop out and store the position of the text for that tag in some map or array.